# Direct reaction of fluorine with benzene will give what product?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My book says fluorine will react with benzene vigorously and involve C–C bond breakage. What does that mean and what product will be formed? It also said that the reaction is of no preparative use.

Comment: OK, you surely must have heard about the reaction known as _burning_, right? Like C6H6+O2$\to$... Well, with fluorine it is pretty much the same, only more violent.